# How can I determine the topmost folder (root) of a relative path?

Tags: c#, .net, path

Given the relative path string:

```
"SomeFolder\\Container\\file.txt"
```

I want to determine the topmost parent or root folder, `"SomeFolder"`.

```
Path.GetPathRoot("SomeFolder\\Container\\file.txt"); // returns empty
```

I'd prefer to avoid "string voodoo" so that this can be ported to systems with different directory separators.

Is there some obvious method that I am overlooking?

Comment: The `Uri` class has many methods for this type of scheme, however I can't say what method will work in all cases.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx will assist with porting string voodoo methods

Comment: As an aside you could just "normalize" the paths to use `/` instead of \, since Windows OSes will happily accept both.

Comment: Downvoters: What do you feel I can do to improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Will suggested use of the `Uri` class, which I have used for some other path operations to great effect.

I solved this with the following method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the path root if absolute, or the topmost folder if relative.
/// The original path is returned if no containers exist.
/// </summary>
public static string GetTopmostFolder(string path)
{
    if (path.StartsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
        path = path.Substring(1);

    Uri inputPath;

    if (Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Absolute, out inputPath))
        return Path.GetPathRoot(path);

    if (Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Relative, out inputPath))
        return path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)[0];

    return path;
}
```

**Edit:**

Modified to strip off leading directory separators. I don't anticipate having any input strings with them, but it's good to plan just in case.

Comment: Interesting approach, however, it breaks if your path is of the form `\\SomeFolder\\Container\\file.txt`.

Comment: A good point. I don't expect that as an input, but I will edit the method with a way to strip leading directory separators off, which I'd consider optional depending on the need.

Comment: Sounds like *"string voodoo"* `=P`

Comment: At least it's cross-platform compatible (we hope) voodoo. :)

Answer (score 0):

From [Path.GetPathRoot Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx):

> Returns the root directory of path, such as
>   "C:\", or null if path is null, or an empty string if path does not
>   contain root directory information.

Your path isn't rooted. That's why you're getting the empty string as a result. You should first check if the path is rooted, before you call `GetPathRoot()`.

```
var somePath = "SomeFolder\\Container\\file.txt";

String root;
if (Path.IsPathRooted(somePath))
    root = Path.GetPathRoot(somePath);
else
    root = somePath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).First();
```

Comment: @Blorgbeard The question is answered by my edits. If the path isn't in a form that the `Path` helpers can work with, I'd resort to string manipulation.